Excel value if now time between 00:00 to 04:00
I want your help.
I need a formula in Excel
=If(Now(time(between 00:00 to 04:00)))than,0.2,"")

Please help, how to use formula for this value.
Thanks
I am trying this, but
A1 = 00:00
B1 = 04:00
C1 = '=Now()
=If(and(c1=<b1,c1=>a1),"",0.2)

it is not working. Please help to use this.

"it is not working" - What does this mean? Can you show some example input values and explain: what result do you get when you try it? What result should you get instead? In what situations is the result wrong (can you see a pattern to what goes wrong)?
